# Run nginx in static IP of server

Tags: nginx, windows-server-2012, static-ip

Sorry for my bad English, I can't explain it well.

I have a VPS with Windows Server 2012 with Nginx and run a Node server at port 4000 and React client at port 3000.

In remote desktop website run at localhost address but when I use static IP of server in other device, I get any response from server.

> This site can’t be reached XXX.XXX.192.176 took too long to respond.

I setup IIS and connected to the server, but when IIS is started, nginx can't start.

nginx is configured as follows:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  sendfile        on;

  keepalive_timeout  65;

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  _;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }
    location /socket.io {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   html;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem:

I just add IP of server as `server_name` and checked the windows firewall for port 80.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  XXX.XXX.192.176; // IP of server

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
    }
    location /socket.io {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
    }
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   html;
    }
  }
```